# static url mapping and routing issue

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I've defined routes mapping here:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "AddPost",
            "Admin/Post/Add/",
            new { controller = "Post", action = "Add" },
            new[] { "mBlog.Admin.Controllers " }
            );
context.MapRoute(
            "admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "mBlog.Admin.Controllers" }
        );
```

"Admin" is an area.

The issue is when I requesting `~/admin/post/add`, I got 404 error, cannot find the resource. But once I removed the first route mapping, I got the desired results.

I've tested with `RouteDebugger`, and the results shows it matches the first route.

Didn't know what's wrong with the first route.

Comment: Please provide more details. You said that a request for /admin/post/add matches the first route. That's what I would expect. What did you expect to happen? Do you have an "Add" method on PostConttroller?

Comment: Yes, I had an "Add" method on PostController. RouteDebugger shows /admin/post/add matching the first route, but I got a 404 error. Once I remove the first route, the second routes matches, and the "Add" action is called. BTW, Admin is an area

Answer (score 0):

try changing `Admin/Post/Add/` to `Admin/Post/Add`